# Problemas al instalar paquete en Google Colab

Tags: python, pytorch

Cuando intento ejecutar

```
import os import torch from ds_ctcdecoder import Alphabet, ctc_beam_search_decoder, Scorer
```

obtengo el error:

> ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last) in <cell line: 29>() 27 import os 28 import torch ---> 29 from ds_ctcdecoder import Alphabet, ctc_beam_search_decoder, Scorer 30 from torch import nn 31 import torchaudio
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ds_ctcdecoder'

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?. He intentado instalar la librería de múltiples maneras pero de ninguna manera lo consigo.

Gracias

Comment: ¿No será `ds-ctcdecoder`?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendaría que pongas cada "importación" o "importe" de librerías en líneas separadas, creo que con eso tendría que estar solucionado tu problema, quedaría algo como esto:

```
import os
import torch
from ds_ctcdecoder import Alphabet, ctc_beam_search_decoder, Scorer
```

Comment: Si pones todo en la misma línea da error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax", no "Module not found".